# Are network task in nodejs ran in a different thread even when called from the main thread?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, rabbitmq, instance

I had a discussion with a teammate on how code ran in a nodejs instance may be used with making network calls and connections. So here is the example, I am under the impression that, when in our code, we connect to rabbitmq and postgresdb using the node modules made to connect to these services (not run them), it will run these modules and there network connections in the same main thread (since we dont explicitly use multithreading) but it seems like, based on this article, the entwork stuff IS used on a diff thread despite doing all the code and etc in the main nodejs thread. Source: `https://scoutapm.com/blog/nodejs-architecture-and-12-best-practices-for-nodejs-development` => `Single-Threaded Event Loop Architecture in Node.js`.

So with this said, does that mean that any network connections/calls are not ran on the main thread?

the reason for asking this is because, i had this debate about implementating some rabbitmq code which is basically a network queue that will listen for something and process it. MY team mate has the producer code and consumer code running in the same nodejs instance (and main thread) since we simple jsut run that code in a setTimeout or setInterval.

To me, i feel like the consumer (that waits and processes it) should be in its own instance or at least its own thread. But that article makes it seem like it is in its own thread.

Can someone help me clarify this?

Comment: That link you posted has nothing to do with using different threads. It advocates using `async` and `await` for handling Promise values.

Comment: In the link, look for the "Single-Threaded Event Loop Architecture in Node.js" section

Comment: @Pointy that above should help u understand where im trying to get at

Comment: Those threads used by the Node runtime are invisible. You can put your code in another process (another Node process scheduled as a process on whatever your operating system platform is), or in the same one; it pretty much doesn't matter. The overwhelming amount of time involved in making and responding to a network request (or any other I/O really) is the latency involved; the processing time is completely minimal.

Comment: @Pointy make sense, i guess as a follow up, would be, is there any pros or cons on using same instance (same thread) but have the network calls use one of these invisible threads? 

think of it like this i guess, 2 node instances, one where we are producer, putting things into a queue or db, and one isntance being consumer (process it) in another instance, vs running everything in same thread/instance in the hopes nodejs internally uses other threads for the network functionality?

Comment: You certainly could do that, but for what it's worth I would recommend making that decision based on code architecture, maintenance, and your own convenience. Performance probably is a very minor issue in a setup like that; people run Node instances as web servers dealing with hundreds of thousands of HTTP requests per minute.

Comment: (I meant "hundreds or thousands", but the point is the same.)